# Cannot resolve method subscribe(rx.Scheduler)

Tags: java, android, system.reactive

So I have this problem with this udemy course I've been following. Everything works fine but I keep getting this error at this one line.

```
Observable<List<String>> userDetailsObservable = Observable.just(userDetails);

    return userDetailsObservable
          Error is here-->  .subscribe(Schedulers.io())

            //Check for user error.
            .map(new Func1<List<String>, Integer>() {
```

It keep getting told that it can't resolve the method so I cast it like it suggests but then I can't use the .map 
Anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` instead of `subscribe(Schedulers.io())`